# Enabling the User to Insert the Data in Access Database

Tags: microsoft-access

I have created a data model in Access Database. 
Tables that are composite parts of the model are loaded with data. Some of the data needs to be loaded manually.

Now I would like to link couple of tables together and give the user the option to insert the missing date in the tables. (I am linking the tables together so that the user doesn't have to work with key, but with the "actual" information that he knows.)

I've never worked with Access Data Base before and therefore I would like to ask you to please instruct and help me on how to accomplish my goal?

Answer (score 0):

***Create a form.***

Forms are used to allow users to enter data into tables. The developer uses controls, like text boxes, on the form to request information needed. Validation and restrictions can be added to the form to ensure data is in the proper format or meets certain criteria before being added to the table.

Not sure what version you are using, but there are plenty of tutorials on the Internet to help you learn to create and use forms. Here is a good place to start - [Create forms for a new Access 2007 database](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/training/create-forms-for-a-new-access-2007-database-RZ010291967.aspx?section=2).